# Adressing timing issues on a pipelined logic circuit

Tags: pwm, oscillator, crystal, duty-cycle

*Original title: How to modify the duty cycle of crystal oscillator?*

I have a 25.175 MHz crystal oscillator with a duty cycle of 50%. How can I reduce the waveform to a 25% duty cycle?

It doesn't have to be really precise. I clock the first part of a logic circuit on my clock's falling edge and the second part on its rising edge. My problem is that the second part is clocked about 8 ns too soon. By decreasing the duty cycle, it should fix the issue.

### More in-depth explanation on what I'm trying to do:

*Keep in mind that I'm really new to electronic so I must have made some mistakes.*

I've built a simple VGA video card with 5 V CMOS (HC) logic chips. I've split the circuit into three parts:

- The first part is triggered on every 8th clock pulse. It computes the next 8 pixels and stores the result in D-type Flip-Flops (DFFs).
- The second part selects the pixel to display at clock rate and stores it in a DFF.
- The third part takes what is in the last DFF and displays it at clock rate.

It's impossible to compute each pixel instantly. That's why the third part is here: the next pixel to display is already present in a DFF.

It's really hard to do any clocked logic running at 25 MHz (40 ns period) when you have to make memory accesses. That's why I compute 8 pixels at a time and then select the one to display.

My problem is on the first pixel of each group of 8. Since I'm using the clock falling edge to latch the 8 next pixels and the clock rising edge to select the next pixel, I only have 20 ns to update the binary counter and select the correct pixel. It's too short and that's why I'm trying to adjust the duty cycle.

### The fix

Let's call the first part, second part and third part, stage 1, 2 and 3 of the pipeline.

The initial plan was to latch the result of stage 1 and 2 at the same time, but it didn't work well. When using the falling and rising edge of the clock as explained above, it worked better but was not perfect.

I reverted back to latching the result of stage 1 and 2 at the same time because the problem was elsewhere.

Indeed, to divide the clock by 8, stage 1 use the same binary counter  as stage 2 (stage 2 use it to select which pixel to display). Thus, stage 1 and 2 are in sync. But because stage 2 use the result of stage 1, one clock pulse later, there should be an offset of one clock pulse between the two stages.

The fix was to pass the output of the binary counter through a clocked DFF to offset the count by one before feeding it to stage 2.

Comment: This is 2021.  Using weird clocks to make logic circuits work made sense from around 1950 to 1980, and was almost scrubbed from new designs by 1990.  You're getting some answers to the question as asked, but you should *start another question* possibly titled "logic circuit needs a weird clock", and ask for help.  You _probably_ need to clock the thing twice as fast, and use some pipelining so that you meet timing with a good steady clock.  Using a circuit that has weird delays built into the clock is practically begging some deity to make your circuit fail when the temperature changes.

Comment: What logic chip are you using and what voltage?  IF you have weird Logic , the you might consider a 4 phase clock derived from 2f

Comment: @TimWescott Actually I'm using pipelining. I've edited the question to explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for expanding the question. (1) Please can you edit it and change the word **execute** everywhere to something else. CPUs execute instructions whereas electronic components and circuits don't. Bricks don't 'execute' hitting the floor when you drop them. (2) Any reason to not use an FPGA and to design your logic circuit in VHDL (or Verilog)? It'd be much easier to develop as you can find and design out all the logic circuit's problems in simulation, then try the design in the FPGA. Dev' boards are cheap, with RAM and some with VGA connectors.

Comment: @TonyM I've a background in computer programing, so that why I use the word "execute" everywhere. I don't really know what word I can use in place of this one, in this context.

Comment: I used to lookup setup and hold times to guarantee latch operation and then use a one shot to delay leading edge to latch with RC diode and gate or similar to exceed counter worst case latency

Comment: @TonyM I'm not using an FPGA because I want to learn electronic. Using an FPGA or a micro-controller would be "cheating". This is a hobby project, I want it to be fun, not effective.

Comment: (An FPGA implements a digital logic circuit, so that's usable, whereas an MCU runs a program and that's not relevant to designing a logic circuit.) I understand and applaud your motives but I don't think it's the right path to get you there. Read up more on synchronous logic design. Use a logic simulator, draw out what you're doing or enter it in VHDL, get it working then still implement that circuit in 74-series or whatever at the end. Learn digital logic there and better. You'll have less temptation to use hacks like squeezed clock or using different edges. Fun is getting it working neat.

Comment: @TonyM Firstly, thanks for the edit, the question is a lot clearer like that. Also, thank you for your tips! Before building the circuit I made a drawing in KiCad but I didn't simulated it and I overlooked this part. But now that I have a functioning video card on breadboard, I would really like that first pixel to be clean.

Comment: If you want to design retro logic then look at how it was done ‘back in the day’. Look at schematics of 70’s and 80’s computers.  The common techniques that cone to mind is  using a series of gates to add up the propogation delay (highly variable), add a capacitor or resistor and capacitor to delay the edge or a delay line (which was a circuit to create a specified delay).  The ‘correct’ way to do it is have a higher clock rate to get a better time resolution but as you’ve found when you get to around 30MHz TTL tends to run out of steam.

Comment: THis is a "race condition" defined by all the timing specs for prop delayt LH,tLH and rise time. etc. It is also sensitive to Vdd as CMOS is faster at higher voltage and cooler temperatures. It is also called a metastable condition, where you can design the race to be stable by choosing the best window for the latch clock by suitable controlled stable delays. It can be done by design in the same phase or delayed any fraction or integer delays of a pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical XY problem: the solution you seek is to an issue that should not be present to begin with.

What you are looking for is called pipelining. The data for the upcoming 8 pixels can be fetched across several clock cycles and stored in a 2nd 8-bit register. Then when it’s needed, you transfer that 2nd latch to the one you already have.

Comment: You're right. I'm currently doing pipelining, but obviously I don't do it well. I'm going to work on this rather than trying to squeeze the clock pulse in a way that could maybe make the thing work.

Answer (score 2):

> *I have a 25.175 MHz crystal with a duty cycle of 50%. How can I reduce
> \$\color{red}{\text{it}}\$ to a 25% duty cycle?*

If by \$\color{red}{\text{it}}\$ you mean the crystal then you can't.

A crystal oscillator is an analogue circuit at its heart and relies on the crystal acting as a linear filter that produces a fixed phase angle (from input to output) of around 180 degrees (when used in conjunction with the correct loading capacitors.

The crystal itself governs the oscillation frequency by "processing" (or allowing to pass) a sinewave of the "right" frequency and, a sinewave has a fixed 50% duty cycle.

You might use a PLL (phase locked loop) and a 25.175 MHz crystal oscillator to generate 50.350 MHz then, use digital methods to divide the frequency by two and gate it with the 50.350 MHz output to obtain a duty of 25%.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have a lot of parts, so I was wondering If I could achieve that with a quick and dirty fix so I don't have to order anything and wait a week. Someone told me that it was possible with a capacitor and some resistors but he couldn't remember exactly how it worked.

Comment: @Cl00e9ment What do you have available and what are you willing to do in terms of complexity, size, etc? How many loads and what kind of logic does all this drive?

Comment: @jonk What I have right now is multiple resistors and capacitors with different values. I also have some logic chips (NAND gates, NOT gates, binary counters, D-type flip flops, compactors). I'm trying to make a really basic VGA "video card".

Comment: @Cl00e9ment Have you considered a simple RC high-pass and an AND gate made either with a couple of very fast BJTs or else a logic gate? I'm not sure it will work, but it strikes me as easy to try out. I'm thinking about 47 Ohm resistor and 33 pF cap, thereabouts as a total guess about the ballpark values. Rising edge thing? Layout will be important and there is NO WAY you can use a protoboard for it. All this assumes you can generate a solid clock, of course.

Comment: @jonk I'll try that

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as @KubaHasntForgottenMonica mentioned, I'm seeking a solution to an issue that should not be present to begin with. So I'll just re-think how to correctly implement pipelining for my circuit in order to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can have the same load capacitance by lowering one and raising the other and keep the same frequency.  This can improve the Rout C rise effects on duty cycle.

series C1 + C2 + parallel Cp(arasitic)= \$C_{load} = \dfrac{C1*C2}{C1+C2}+C_p\$

- Adding a series R (10k) increases slew rate and reduces XTAL Pwr (uW) , Reducing Cin and increasing Cout increases the Vin signal level

2. if RdsOn for Pch and Nch are different or you are using a gate with unsymmetrical prop delays. the average threshold voltage may be unstable. This is not good. so you want to maximize the input signal by the above method to reduce the sensitivity to threshold induced duty cycle shift.
3. However understanding these factors allows you to alter the Rfb self bias with an offset DC voltage.

I would need your design specs, schematic and parts list to recommend a fix.

[But this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0CM8QGYAcAmAdAdgGzsg3gBZkBOMsXYqSKKCGBeAKACcRj5cR51UUkdL37heYCWHYowNPgOSyQ6dDQjJFkqRy49VEYtWXEIjXFqkB3YxHky5oq4OEqau5avAsA8p24iBQwcBUxYAJU5UCFdI2zJhU05GMVNMSBYAcxRUOTxsuXiU6Xc7EvMxdGwWa0Vg5wCvGqEPGlqWrwBjertkZvg82zhEXkwTSHISWSp4cjJkcEwJVi7e4X6eVfb1IeFYLGRSPDBVYmx0bmwyNUWwVhqlGP0tli4XEwanmKQwAB0AZywqGwQ3g-1gYEwc1QyFwqByVHM-Fu-whS3A-yYJDByG4ow0OUU8DIqEgxNwKJu3wpkkuFDp9IZYNREiBFGI4zIsIokCE6BR6L+uFGLAAkn49J4yol4GkoNV8rw8pt1l4ssQospIDx1dEzkUAMqcIxPHU2MRIABmAEMADZ-aAVF5geZCAR2XBa3iFRgAfWQ6B9YB97IRwchlFw8XgkFI6GdZEDN1uPoQPtYJhdxBocYEuD1lQSnD9AaDJBh8FQfswFfkHpyZDwqDzick8BTbYDxD98vcMV77ykQA) will give you the jist of it.
[image]

27 ohms emulates 74ALCxx 5V logic

There are many other ways to do this but depends on the extra details you provide in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as @KubaHasntForgottenMonica mentioned, I'm seeking a solution to an issue that should not be present to begin with. So I'll just re-think how to correctly implement pipelining for my circuit in order to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you realize you can easily increase your timing margin by switching from 74HC to 74AC family logic?  Then a pullup from 1 to 10M will reduce the duty cycle output and pulldown increase it.

Comment: Also there is a way to use a full clock cycle to increment and calculate a new result and latch it in 1 clock cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. After a good night of sleep, I found were the problem was. I updated my question to explain where was the issue.

Comment: The Asymmetry of your clock is a design problem that should not be ignored, but you have provided no details.